# trying to inactivate a apex class in Production using Workbench

Tags: apex

I am using workbench to inactivate a class or trigger in the PROD system. On doing an update on status from active to inactive, am getting ERROR : INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY.. Insufficient Access Rights On Cross-reference Id......I have modiy all & view all permission.#
I just want to inactivate an existing class or trigger  for temprory  purpose. I even tried to inactivate in TEST sandbox then deploy to PROD,then it fails with coverage failure error.
What would be the best way to resolved it>

Comment: What is the entire message? And what is the file you are trying to deploy? Some more specifics on what you are sending and what you are getting will help to narrow the answer down

Comment: So when you delete/inactivate a trigger/class in Prod, it runs all tests to check you didn't break anything - that, and the fact you can't deploy from the Sandbox suggests you have a problem in your tests. Fix that, and you should be able to make the changes you want...

Comment: @BritishBoyinDC: is there an alternative to by pass it via some test class to reach 75% coverage.As these classes and triggers are pre-existing in the system and are already available in PROD for use-. And I don't want to mess around whats already working.

Comment: Not that I know of in Prod...you'll need to see why the tests are failing...